# Magento 2 - Event equivalent to checkout_cart_product_add_after for admin

Tags: magento2, admin, event-observer

I am using **checkout_cart_product_add_after** and **checkout_cart_product_update_after** events for making customization using observer on front-end this works properly there but in admin side this events are not working.

I guess this events are only for front-end. can any one please tell me how to implement this event observer in admin or any other event which is equivalent to this events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best idea to use `sales_quote_product_add_after` .

> ```
> $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_quote_product_add_after', ['items' => $items]);
> ```

**This event is fire when an item will added in and when item will be update**

For this event, *you can current quote items list*
using `$observer->getItems()`

***This event is fire both for frontend and   backend***

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `events.xml` situated? In `etc`, `etc/frontend` or `etc/adminhtml`? If it's only in `etc/frontend` you need to move you `events.xml` to `etc`, or add an `events.xml`-file to your `etc/adminhtml`-folder with a similar event.

Another thing could be that the checkout is indeed something that is frontend-only. If you're using the admin, you're not using a checkout, but you're creating a quote / order. In that case you might want to take a look at `Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Save()`. This is the controller that handles the saving of an order from the admin and might be a good starting point.

If I'm running through the code I finally come to a method called `Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create::createOrder()`. This order dispatches an event called `checkout_submit_all_after`, but because it's a public method as well you could also use a plugin / interceptor for this, depending on your needs. Make sure to put your `di.xml` or `events.xml` in the `etc/adminhtml`-folder, otherwise they might collide with your previously checkout-related events. It could be even possible that if you hook into this method, the checkout-events can already be obsolete.

I hope this helps you a bit. I haven't tried it out, but I think it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Giel for your answer and explanation but answer of Amit works for me.